# Why tags are displayed bellow the content and not inside

Tags: theme-development, tags, the-content

I am developing a theme for myself and I was wondering why wordpress tags are allways displayed bellow the_content.

I know that this can be done via shortcode, but I would like to know if this is for seo purposes, or there is any technical reason?

I´am  asking because I didn´t find any information on the web...

My code:

in functions.php ([found in here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-show-tags-in-a-post))

```
function tags_in_post($atts) {    // [tags] outputs post's tags in a span
global $post;
$tags = '<span class="post-tags">';
ob_start();
the_tags( '<span class="post-tags">', ', ', '</span>' );
$tags = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $tags;
}
add_shortcode ('tags', 'tags_in_post');
```

Than this shorttag [tags] must be used inside the wordpress editor.

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: @GhostToast edited

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly -- edit meta tags? Why not use an SEO Plugin, such as Yoast's: [WordPress SEO Plugin • Search Engine Optimization Plugin • Yoast](http://yoast.com/wordpress/seo/)

Comment: I am trying to put the tags inside the post content and not at the top or bottom of the post itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I look closely, seems our actual question is "Why does WordPress put Post Tags at the bottom of a Post?"

The answer depends on the theme, of course. But, most themes put them after a post's body so that you can use it as part of browsing away from that post, to get involved with further reading. Basically like saying, "You've been reading about: Toys, Babies, Books" where each of those items is a link to, presumably, articles on those topics.

The idea of having them at the end of the article is so you don't get bored too quickly and jump off to read something else.

Unless you mean something else by `tags` as that can be a pretty vague thing around these parts.

Comment: First of all, thanks! The title of my question should be the one you mentioned. So, it doesn't hurt my seo if I put them inside the content, right?

Comment: Great. If this answer satisfies your curiosity, please select it as "correct". If not, please explain.